# Trying to get Gridster to call functions like disable but $('.gridster ul').gridster().data('gridster'); not working

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, gridster

I am using angular gridster, and I want to be able to do stuff like remove an item or disable it temporarily.

[How to remove a single widget from gridster.js by his dynamically created id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20705110/how-to-remove-a-single-widget-from-gridster-js-by-his-dynamically-created-id)
[HighStocks draggable element interfering with gridster dragging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24960994/highstocks-draggable-element-interfering-with-gridster-dragging)

However, when I try to use the line $('.gridster ul').gridster().data('gridster');, I gett an error TypeError: $(...).gridster is not a function

Comment: What code do you use: the code of the question or from one of the answers?

Comment: Please ensure that you load all required files, because error can be caused by incorrect loading modules.

Comment: Mathias, I've tried different variations of $('.gridster ul').gridster().data('gridster') ... $('.gridster ul') gets me an object, but I can' invoke much on it.

Answer (score 0):

At first, you have to initialise `gridster`. For that, you can use the below code

```
$(".gridster ul").gridster({
       widget_margins: [10, 10],
       widget_base_dimensions: [140, 140]
 });
```

the base dimension is the width and height in pixels for a single tile

then you can call

```
var gridster = $("#demo-2 ul").gridster().data('gridster'); //object of gridster
```